# Oracle doesnt understand Laravel SQL queries

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I am trying to execute to sql query with laravel eloquent.

But Oracle doesnt understand laravel query.

Here is Laravel Code:

```
    public function postLogincheck(Request $request){


    $rules = array(
        'name'    => 'required|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
    );

    $messages = array(
        'required'=>':attribute alanı gereklidir.',
        'min'=>':attribute alanına en az :min karakter girmelisiniz',
        'alphaNum'=>':attribute alanına alfanümerik karakterler girebilirsiniz'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules,$messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {

        if (Auth::attempt(array('name' => $request->name, 'password' => $request->password))) {

            flash()->success('Giriş başarılı');

            return Redirect::to('/');

        }

        flash()->error('Giriş başarısız');

        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }

}
```

This method checking the user for login.And laravel convert login query like this:

```
 select * from (select * from ReportUsers where upper(name) = upper(tsim)) where rownum = 1
```

But oracle expecting this query:

```
 select * from (select * from "ReportUsers" where upper("name") = upper('tsim')) where rownum = 1
```

I am using [yajra laravel-oci8 connector](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8) for connecting the Oracle DB.

Also I am getting this error cause of this issue:

```
    Error Code : 942
Error Message : ORA-00942: tablo veya görüntü mevcut degil
Position : 29
Statement : select * from (select * from ReportUsers where upper(name) = upper(:p0)) where rownum = 1
Bindings : [tsim,tsim]
(SQL: select * from (select * from ReportUsers where upper(name) = upper(tsim)) where rownum = 1)
```

How can I gain this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You sure about that?  SQL is pretty standardized, I don't work with Oracle anymore but I don't ever remember quoting table or column names.  What is your error message?

Comment: @Devon you'd have to doublequote table/column names if they're defined as case sensitive. Which is, in general, a complete PITA imho!

Comment: @Devon Yes I am sure.And I edited the question to see error message.

Comment: If possible rename the table so that its name isn't case sensitive: `rename "ReportUsers" to reportusers;`

Comment: @Boneist, yeah that is a PITA.  I guess I always used the snake_case convention.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to go out on a limb here, since I don't have any way of testing it right now.

Try adding:

```
protected $table = '"ReportUsers"';
```

To your model.

If it doesn't work, I'll remove this.

Comment: The problem is not only table name format but also table properties format.Like `name` should be "name".

Comment: From the comments, it seems like that is only the case for upper case characters.  Did you try this and confirm?

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with the same problem, just comment on line 206 of the file OracleGrammar.php that will be solved, it tests if it is a reserved word back with the names in uppercase.

//$value = $this->isReserved($value) ? Str::lower($value) : Str::upper($value);

The file path is vendor->yajra->laravel-oci8->src->Oci8->query->Grammars